# How can I create a disabled effect on <input>,<select> and <img> tags with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I create a disabled effect on , and  tags with jQuery to indicate to user that they aren't editable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#elementId').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
```

Comment: $('#elementId').attr('disabled', 'disabled')

or 

$('#elementId').attr('disabled', true)

which is right?

Comment: $('img').attr('disabled', 'disabled'),what's the effect of disabling img?

Comment: correct, better to make the image opaque I would think, what do you want to do?

Comment: $('#imageId').fadeTo('slow', 0.2) for example-

Comment: is fadeTo a built-in function of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Depending on which DOCTYPE he's using, it should not be correct, use 'disabled=disabled' with xhtml 1.0

Comment: what's the effect of disabling img?

Comment: @redsquare ,tried, the "disabled" attribute has no effect to img:(

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ID_OF_THE_ELEMENT").attr("disabled","disabled");
```